# PyCharm right click start running with current path as parameter

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I'm working on PyCharm right now and I was wondering if there is a way to add a run option when right click on a folder, with the folder path as the first parameter when running. I know in `edit configurations` I could manually edit the script path and parameters to the folder location. But I was wondering if there's a faster way since I have a lot different folder paths as options.

I considered building a plugin for this, but I'm not too familiar with the IDEA platform nor java, and I feel like there might be an alternative solution to creating a whole new plugin. Thanks for much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of resources that cover the plugin development for the IntelliJ-based IDEs, like [IntelliJ Platform SDK Docs](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs) or [IntelliJ Platform Plugin Template](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template).

Check also the [`intellij-plugin`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intellij-plugin/info) tag details for more links.